# Linker hangs when compiling a simple eigen3 program on Win10

Tags: c++, r, linker, eigen, rtools

I am using the build tools provided by Rtools.

gcc version 8.3.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 (Built by Jeronen for the R-project)

GNU ld version 2.33.1

eigen version 3.4.0

I have been testing various functions of the eigen package, and when I calculated the singular values using the `BDCSVD` object, the linker just hangs with full cpu usage. The following line is causing the trouble:

```cpp
BDCSVD<MatrixXd> svd(m, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);
```

This line of code compiles fine. Just the particular linker does not return. I have waited a few minutes for the linker, but it just won't return.

On the other hand, when I used the latest `gcc` from the Windows Linux subsystem. Everything worked fine. So is this a known issue? Can it be easily fixed (but still using the build system provided by Rtools in Windows)?

PS: I have encounted this issue several times before, but the cpp files were much more complex, so I wasn't sure back then what caused the hanging linker.

Update:
A code sample is provided below. I configured my Windows copy of eigen3 using the "Unix Makefiles" option, since I do not have Visual Studio and don't want to download it.

Here is the cpp file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
double data[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    data[i] = i;
}

Map<MatrixXd> m(data, 3, 3);
BDCSVD<MatrixXd> svd(m, ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV);

auto v = svd.singularValues();

cout << "condition #: " << v.maxCoeff() / v.minCoeff() << endl;
}
```

I was trying to calculate the condition number of a singular matrix here.

Compiled using command line:

```sh
g++ -I"my eigen lib" t.cpp -o t.exe
```

where `g++` comes from Rtools, "my eigen lib" is the eigen include directory, `t.cpp` the cpp file, and `t.exe` the build target.

Surprisingly or not, when I changed the algo from `BDCSVD` to `JacobSVD`, the compilation would succeed, even though `BDCSVD` defaults to `JacobSVD` for small matrices.

`cc1plus` and `as` both returned normally. `ld` keeps running forever, it seems.

Edits:
It's been awhile, but I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: I think `BDCSVD` is quite heavy regarding template instantiations. Did you compile with optimizations? Can you provide a minimal example and the command line you used for compiling?